# How to find online touristic information, the kind we should not ask for on this site?

Tags: online-resources, tourism

We regularly have to close questions by new users who ask for what to do or where to go in a popular tourist destination.
There is a lot of touristic information online, as well as in travel books, but these people clearly do not know how to look for it.

How would you tell people to start their online search?
Is there one 'will always work' search term or sentence which we can point out to them (only insert your required destination into the it) or do you need to know where the person in going before you can help them with the search.

Comment: I was about to suggest going to a book store - or better yet the local public library if one is available, and browsing the applicable volumes of Lonely Planet, until I saw "their online search".

Comment: @uhoh, I would personally also advise that but I had to place some restrictions otherwise the question would be very broad.

Comment: Should this be a community wiki question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there one 'will always work' search term or sentence which we can point out to them

I'd recommend to search for the official Ministry of Tourism sites using the following search term: *"Tourism + country you are interested in"*.
Some results (I'm using the DuckDuckGo engine):

- "Tourism Portugal": 1st entry [VisitPortugal](https://www.visitportugal.com/en)
- "Tourism Austria": 1st entry [Holidays in Austria | Your Official Travel Guide](https://www.austria.info)
- "Tourism Australia": 1st entry [Tourism Australia](http://tourism.australia.com/)
- "Tourism Zimbabwe": 1st entry [Visit Zimbabwe](https://zimbabwetourism.net/)

Answer (score 15):

A good place to begin is [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Main_Page).

It's crowd-sourced (so there's neither selling nor any fiscal agenda) and has been around sufficiently so it has developed both overview and in-depth information.

Comment: How does Wikivoyage relate to [Wikitravel](https://wikitravel.org/en/Main_Page)?

Comment: @StephanKolassa https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/882/1810

Comment: Although it's true for wikivoyage, it does not follow automatically that services based on crowdsourcing are not selling or serving a fiscal agenda.  Google has lots of data from crowdsourcing and certainly does.

Answer (score 5):

> what to do or where to go in a popular tourist destination.

- https://www.google.com/travel/things-to-do
- https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions
- Google "things to do in + [Name of the place]"
- https://www.google.com/maps, search for the place, then click on "things to do":

  [image]

Answer (score -2):

A bit of an "out of the box" answer: try [ChatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/). It's an AI system that generates answers to arbitrary questions and can serve as a starting point for generic tourist queries. Beware that it frequently provides inaccurate/misleading answers, so travelers should double check the outputs in Google before finalizing their plans. For example, here's the ChatGPT/GPT-4 response to *What are some cheap things to see in New York City besides parks and museums?*

> New York City offers numerous inexpensive or free attractions beyond
> parks and museums. Here are ten options to consider:
>
> 1. Staten Island Ferry: Take a free ride on the Staten Island Ferry, enjoying spectacular views of the Statue of Liberty, Ellis Island, and
>    the Manhattan skyline.
> 2. Times Square: Visit this iconic location, famous for its bright lights, billboards, and street performers.
> 3. 9/11 Memorial: Pay your respects at this poignant tribute to the victims of the September 11 attacks. Admission is free, but there may
>    be a fee to enter the museum.
> 4. Brooklyn Bridge: Walk or bike across this historic bridge, taking in the stunning skyline views of Manhattan and Brooklyn.
> 5. High Line: Stroll along this elevated park and greenway built on a former railway line, admiring the public art and architecture along
>    the way.
> 6. Grand Central Terminal: Explore this beautiful, historic train station, known for its Beaux-Arts architecture and celestial ceiling
>    mural.
> 7. Public Libraries: Visit the New York Public Library's main branch, the Stephen A. Schwarzman Building, to see the stunning architecture
>    and famous Reading Room, or visit other branches for free events and
>    workshops.
> 8. Street Art: Discover the city's vibrant street art scene, particularly in neighborhoods like Bushwick, Williamsburg, and the
>    Lower East Side.
> 9. Free Outdoor Performances: During warmer months, enjoy free outdoor events such as Shakespeare in the Park, SummerStage, and the
>    Washington Square Music Festival.
> 10. Window Shopping: Take a leisurely walk along Fifth Avenue or through SoHo, enjoying the window displays and unique architecture
>     without spending a dime.
>
> Remember to check for any updates or changes
> to admission fees and hours before visiting these attractions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141502/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathanreez-how-to-find-online-touristic-information-t).